# Accessing the Microsoft Graph after OpenId Connect Azure AD Callback

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

Fundamentally all I need to do is grab a users profile photo after successful login (asp.net 4.8) since it doesn't seem that I can request the photo to come over with the login claims.

This is the callback handler

```
SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification
```

This is how I get the Identity from that callback and it's all there looking good

```
var identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
```

So I'm trying to callback with RestSharp

```
var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://graph.microsoft.com");
                var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest($"/v1.0/users/{email}/photo/$value", RestSharp.Method.GET);
                var callbackResult = client.Execute(request);
                Debugger.Break();
                if (callbackResult.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Debugger.Break();
                }
```

But it keeps (I suppose OBVIOUSLY) coming back as unauthorized.  Is there some token or something I can use now that the user has authenticated to add a header or querystring or something that will just get me the extra data easily?

Comment: Is there any reason to not use the [official c# SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet)? All plumbing is probably yet handled

Comment: OpenId Connect is authenticating through a CMS, so there's no code I really have access to outside of the TokenValidationHandler callback I override. Since I really just need the avatar I thought a simple endpoint callback with maybe some token somewhere in what I already have would be the easiest solution.

Comment: can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70978345/14574199) help you? Or [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapp-openidconnect)?